# Is there a way to stop a line of code working after one use

Tags: python

I am trying to reload the code if the question has an invalid answer

```
answer = ("Charge your phone fully and hold the power button until switch it on.")
question = input("Does your phone turn on").lower()
if question == 'no':
    print (answer)
if question == 'yes':
    import sys
    import q2
    mymoduleq1 = sys.modules[q2]
    print (mymoduleq1.var1)
    print (mymoduleq1.var2)
else:
    import sys
    import q1
    mymoduleq_1 = sys.modules[q1]
    print (mymoduleq_1.var1)
    print (mymoduleq_1.var2)
```

The code stops working after one reload because of the line

```
mymoduleq_1 = sys.modules[q1]
```

I was wondering if there was a way to turn it off after one run

Thanks

Comment: You could always maintain a Boolean variable which is checked before running the statement and flipped after the first run

Comment: What exactly are you trying? I don't think you should use `sys.modules` in that way.

Comment: Are you sure this code even works the first time around? I would expect `sys.modules[q2]` to fail with a KeyError because `sys.modules`' keys are strings, not modules.